# How can i access the navigation prop of the "DrawerCustom.Navigator" component, from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native and im trying to build an app where the toolbar is above the drawer, and the toolbar has a button which allows to open the drawer, like in the image:
[image]

As you can see what im trying to achieve is to always have the toolbar visible, even when the drawer is open.
I've managed to acomplish that, the problem is that since the toolbar is outside the "DrawerCustom.Navigator" component i can't access the prop navigation inside the toolbar component, which i need to open the drawer everytime the button is clicked(button with the 3 black bars).
Here's how i have the toolbar and drawer components placed:

```
<NavigationContainer>
          <View style={{...styles.default,...styles.marginTopPhone}}> 
            <ToolbarLogged toggleDrawer={()=>{navigation.toggleDrawer()}}
                idLang={(stringLang==strings_pt)?1:2} lang={stringLang}/>
            <DrawerCustom.Navigator ref={DrawerRef} drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent langFile={stringLang} lang={(stringLang==strings_pt)? 1 : 0}  {...{...props}}/>}>
                <DrawerCustom.Screen name='Dashboard' component={makeLayout} initialParams={{ name: stringLang.dashboard}}/>
                <DrawerCustom.Screen name='Condominium' component={makeLayout} initialParams={{ name: stringLang.condominium}}/>
                <DrawerCustom.Screen name='Profile' component={makeLayout} initialParams={{ name: stringLang.profile}}/>
                <DrawerCustom.Screen name='Signout' component={Signout} />
            </DrawerCustom.Navigator>
          </View>
</NavigationContainer>
```

the makeLayout component that each screen has is a function that loads the current screen depending on the Parameter "name", if the name is profile then the makeLayout function will load the profile screen.

Comment: pass the function for toggling to the component as an prop to access it there

Comment: i've tried that, in fact you can see it in my code "toggleDrawer={()=>{navigation.toggleDrawer()}}" the problem is that i cant access the navigation prop, so the app just crashes when props.toggleDrawer() is called

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 'useNavigation' hook inside the ToolbarLogged component which will give you access to navigation. This will work as long as the component is inside the NavigationContainer.

The below is a sample for a button, you can do the same for your component as well

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function MyBackButton() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title="Back"
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.toggleDrawer();
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

You can check the [reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) for more details